# Boot problem 12.04.4 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, graphics, password-recovery

Good morning to all.
I cannot make my system boot.

I went into recovery mode and I always get the same message:

> The system is running in low graphics mode.
>
> Your screen graphics card and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You need to configure these yourself.

I press enter.

Next message:

```
What you like to do?

1. Run in low graphics for just one session    
2. Reconfigure graphics
3. Troubleshoot the error
4. Exit to console login
```

I choose option one

Next screen

```
Stand by for one minute while the display restarts
```

I wait two or three or more minutes nothing happens.

If I press ok, Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS asks me to login.

I put my password (the one I use for installing apps) and then it asks me for password,but I do not have a second password

If I put the same or nothing out says login incorrect.
And I am stuck.

In addition I ran memory test start up test hard disc test everything is ok

Comment: you can try opening recovery mode add new user. may be this could help.

Comment: go to prompt-shell... adduser lisa.... passwd lisa... thats it.

Comment: There is no option in recovery to add new user. After it runs I get: Resume normal boot, try to make free space, run in failsafe graphic mode, check all file systems, update grab boot loader, enable net working, drop to root shell prompt and system summary... Dunno what to choose.

Comment: Okay. Chose the option `Exit to console login`, then wait for it to load. It will show `Computer Name Login:` Type your username and press enter. Wait a bit and it will say `Password`. Type your password, and press enter. You will then be able to run commands, so try running `sudo lightdm`

Comment: I chose drop to root shell prompt and I typed sudo lightdm. Black screen with a blinking cursor. If I go to console login I get incorrect login. I put loginame the name of the PC and password the one I use for apps. I see no light :(